# MySQLi output error

Tags: php, database, mysqli, rows

I have a problem. I have two tables in my database which I want to write as an output (their names) but it always writes only the first one in the database. Can anybody fix my code and explain why that fix is necessary?

```
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SHOW TABLES");
      while($tableName = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {

                $table = $tableName[0];

                $result2 = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `".$table."`");

                $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `".$table."`";
                $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
                $rows = mysqli_fetch_row($result);

                $querys = "SELECT * FROM `".$table."` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
                $resulty = mysqli_query($conn, $querys);

                $rowsy = mysqli_fetch_row($resulty);

            while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2))
      {
                $p = $row2['authoroftopic'];
                $s = $rows[0];
                $l = $rowsy[1];
                        echo "<div class='discussionTable'>
                            <div class='dcolumn' style='width: 60%; position: absolute; padding-left: 10px;'>
                                <b><h3 style='padding: 15px;'><a href='discussion_gaming.php' style='color: white'>$table</a></b><br><p style='font-size: 13px'>Author: $p</p></h3>
                            </div>
                            <div style='padding-top: 10px;'>
                            <div class='dcolumn' style='width: 30%; float: right;'>
                                <p style='padding: 15px; line-height: 0px'>Total comments: $s</p>
                                <p style='padding-left: 15px; padding-top: 0px; line-height: 0px'>Last comment by: $l</p>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>";
            }
       }
```

Comment: Can you explain further what goes wrong with that code?

Comment: Basically, Image there's nothing in that database (no table created). You create one table with parameters in it. That one is showing perfectly using that code. But if I create another one. The one before is replaced by the one I have just created and that table before does not show anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the variable `$result` for two result sets at the same time - the first to hold the list of available tables, and the second one to gather data from a single table. You should rename one of the two occurences to not override the outer result within the loop

Comment: This was the issue. From now on, I'll be more careful about how I choose my variables' names. Thank you :)